# get the selected arry list custom object item on listview to pass anther activity?

Tags: android, object

i have faced problem to get the selected array list item on my list view.
here is my code:

```
ArrayList<Doctor> doctorList = new ArrayList<Doctor>();//this is the resources of my List.
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, doctorList));
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> obj = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();

        Doctor aDoc=(Doctor)l.getItemAtPosition(position);//this line show error

        obj.put("hashmapkey", aDoc);
        Intent inew = new Intent(DoctorsListActivity.this,
                DoctorBioDataActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();

        b.putSerializable("bundleobj", obj);
        inew.putExtras(b);

        startActivity(inew);
    }`
```

**i just get the selected array list item object to pass next activity ** 
please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using

```
Doctor aDoc=(Doctor)l.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

use your `ArrayList doctorList;` to get `Object` from it like this:

```
Doctor aDoc = doctorList.get(position);
```